# Search and sort not working for unicode strings

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sorting, search

I have a database where names are stored in unicode nvarchar field in amharic language. I want to search and sort the data and I used this code.

```
student=student.Where(s=>s.Name.Contains(searchString));
student=student.Orderby(s=>s.Name);
```

student is a db context class. Both the search and sort doesn't work. It works for English string but for amharic string it brings all records unfiltered an unsorted.

What can I do?

Comment: these C# code will translated to T-SQL statement, where SQL Server takes control of string comparison and ordering. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

> *Right click* on your database > Properties > Options > **Collation**

Choose one item according to your locale.

Comment: I have set the collation to the appropriate one listed from microsoft. Also used tsql to select data. But it is not working. I think I need to change the system locale. But threre is no locale for amharic in the system locale list. How can I add it?

Comment: **Control Panel > Language**. Then on the left panel click on 'Change date, time, or number formats'. Then go to "Location" tab and set _Home location_ to {**Ethiopia**}.